# Generic arguments of the interface method

Tags: typescript, generics, types

There is interface:

```
interface BaseConfig<T = number> {
  doSomething(value: T): void;
}
```

There is a function that accepts this interface at the arguments:

```js
function test(config: BaseConfig<number> | BaseConfig<string>) {}
```

Question: Why `value` is any? I expect it to be `string | number`.

```
test({
  doSomething(value) {} // <-- value is any
});
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=23#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMIHsQzADmAPACrIC8yIArgLYBG0AfMgN4BQyyAJrgGVc9CGAAWoIgAoAbnAA2tCAC5kZAJSqZuYLwDcnAL6dOMWiARhg+ZJAxgpCfISKr0WPAWIk6TVsgAfNEwcZ297KEkWdQ5jTjsHLh5+IRFxSVkFJRj2QwAaI3UDIA)

NOTE: If use generic not at the arguments, but at the response – everything is OK.

```
interface BaseConfig<T = number> {
  doSomething(): T;
}

function test(config: BaseConfig<number> | BaseConfig<string>) {}

test({
  doSomething() {
    return 1; // exepct to return only number ot string
  },
});
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMIHsQzADmAPACrIC8yIArgLYBG0AfMgN4BQyyAJrgGVc9CGAAWoIgAoAlAC5kZANycAvp04xaIBGGD5kkDGCkJ8hIgvRY8BYiTpNWyAD5pMOc-eNRJLGRzqnEYmXDz8QiLikrIc3DzIUKK0UCDIAIxKyAD02cgQAB4QAA66hriJyanI+AA2AJ40DMxQNWDIPpLxqgA0ajJKQA)

Answer (score 1):

combine types inside of the generic

```js
function test(config: BaseConfig<number | string>) {}
```

the problem with `BaseConfig<number> | BaseConfig<string>` is that TS doesn't combine similar types in case of union, read it as `A | B`.

it means the `config` can be either `BaseConfig<number>` or `BaseConfig<string>` and when you declare `doSomething(value) {}` typescript doesn't know whether it is `BaseConfig<number>` or `BaseConfig<string>` and leaves it up to you to provide type (simply add `value: number` or `value: string`). (it's enough to implement one type, not both of them).

When without union TS knows that it's exactly `BaseConfig<number | string>` and `value` is its generic which is `number | string`.

Comment: union types inside generic will not work for me. I very simplified my example.  Anyway, why does it works correctly for the return statement?

Comment: if union doesn't work then you need to define callback correctly so TS can understand its type. For return it works because `1` has `number` type when `value` wasn't typed. if you put `value: number` it will work too.